# Interstitial Ads are not showing

Tags: android, interstitial

i want to show ad when user click to read a pdf file. No Errors only interstitial ads are not showing before pdf show while banners ads are showing. Kindly help me thanks in Advance.
Here is code of java file where i want to show interstitial Ad,

```
package com.example.chickenfarmingurduguidebook;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;

        import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;
        import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
        import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
        import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
        import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
        import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
        import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;

public class book1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    PDFView book1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book1);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        MobileAds.initialize(this,
                "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        book1 = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfbook1);
        book1.fromAsset("book1.pdf").load();

    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add listener to find error.

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded() {
        // Code to be executed when an ad finishes loading.
    }

@Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
    }

  @Override
    public void onAdOpened() {
        // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked() {
        // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLeftApplication() {
        // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // Code to be executed when the interstitial ad is closed.
    }
});
```

And log the error code and post..
Or find the error yourself.

If you ost the error code I can tell what is happening.. Or use the below code list..
And If this is helpful please mark as a correct answer..

Common Error Codes are :

Error Code 0 : ERROR_CODE_INTERNAL_ERROR
This indicates that something happened internally; for instance, an invalid response was received from the ad server.

Newly created Ad Units can take upto 2 hours to become active (SpinUp Time). Any Ad requests from newly created Ad Units would also receive Error Code 0 in response to Ad requests until they are ready to serve live ads.

What to do? Test Ads!!

Error Code 1 : ERROR_CODE_INVALID_REQUEST
The ad request was invalid; for instance, the ad unit ID was incorrect.

This commonly suggests that the Ad Request implementation is not as per the SDK’s requirements - Resources like the  sample codes and sample apps provided in the developer documentation can help in implementing the functions correctly.

Error Code 2 : ERROR_CODE_NETWORK_ERROR

The ad request was unsuccessful due to network connectivity.

This could be due to a user’s phone switching networks or network disturbances distorting the communication between the app and the Ad Server. Some Telecom providers may also limit specific traffic due to policy, which can also lead to such an error.

Error Code 3 : ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL
Description (Dev Docs Link) : The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.

Why is  it Happening : Advertisers can target specific regions, platforms and user profiles based on business relevance, which can sometimes result in lower availability of Ads for a particular region or user profile. Error code suggests that the implementation is correct, and that the Ad Request was not filled because of lack of availability of a suitable Ad at that particular instant of time when an Ad Request was sent from the app.

Policy related restrictions on certain Apps or Ad Units will also lead to Error Code 3 being returned in response to Ad Requests.

And you can log the error using

```
  @Override
    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        Log.i("myAdErrorCode",errorCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
fullScreenBanner.show();
```

in onAdLoaded in InterstitialAdEventListener

```
fullScreenBanner.setInterstitialAdEventListener(new InterstitialAdEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                fullScreenBanner.show();
            }
```